# indexeddb - is it possible get item at position i from an index

Tags: html, indexeddb

I have an indexeddb index of objects sorted by timestamp. I need to be able to get the ith element of the index. (i.e. get the 100th element NOT get the element before or after a particular timestamp / key) Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use [`advance`](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBCursor-advance-void-unsigned-long-count) method of the cursor.

```
cursor.advance(100); // move cursor to 100th record
```